# MVC routing with multiple parameter with different parameter name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

In my home controller, I have 3 Action methods. 
which is give below.

```
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Index2(int did,int docType)
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Index3(int uid,int docId,int typeId)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

As I had given diffrent parameter name in each action methods so I have to change in `Route.config`.

I have Done this

**Method  1**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{did}/{docType}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index2", did = UrlParameter.Optional, docType = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{uid}/{docId}/{typeId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index3", uid = UrlParameter.Optional, docId = UrlParameter.Optional, typeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but it is giving me exception like

```
Home' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique
```

So I have change it to like this

**Method 2**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{did}/{docType}/{uid}/{docId}/{typeId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, did = UrlParameter.Optional, docType = UrlParameter.Optional, uid = UrlParameter.Optional, docId = UrlParameter.Optional, typeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I hit Url like

http://localhost:50958/Home/Index/2

http://localhost:50958/Home/Index2/2/3

http://localhost:50958/Home/Index3/2/3/4

it throwing me exception.

**This is Solution.**

As suggested by Stephen Muecke

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{did}/{docType}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index2", did = UrlParameter.Optional, docType = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "User",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{uid}/{docId}/{typeId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index3", uid = UrlParameter.Optional, docId = UrlParameter.Optional, typeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: The reason for the first error is because your first 2 route definitions have `name: "Home",` - they need to be unique. Just change one or the other

Comment: @StephenMuecke:But my all the actions are in Home Controller.

Comment: That has nothing at all do do with it. Call then anything you want. They just need to be unique

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks . It works. can it be possible by method 2.

Comment: I doubt it. Only the last parameter can be optional so you would need to provide at least 5 parameters every time to avoid ambiguity. Note also the `name` property is used by methods such as `@Html.RouteLink("XYZ");` which matches `routes.MapRoute( name: "XYZ, ...)`

Comment: You should put that as an answer, then except it so the question is not left unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had given same name to all route. and route name must be unique, now i have rename the route with different name.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{did}/{docType}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index2", did = UrlParameter.Optional, docType = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "User",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{uid}/{docId}/{typeId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index3", uid = UrlParameter.Optional, docId = UrlParameter.Optional, typeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Route name should be unique, You have two routes with same name: "Home"